# How can I insert or embed multiple youtube videos in one post in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube

How can I insert or embed multiple youtube videos in one post in wordpress?

What I want to do is here the link.*sorry it is Japanese website.

You can see a video about fireworks and there are three links under the video which are Sleeping Dog ,Hiyoko of Tea, and Tokyo DIsney land fire works.

Once you click the link one of them, the display automatically shows the video that you click.

Could you tell me how to write the code? 
I think it was written by javascript.

I have a website by WordPress.

the link is here 
http://phpjavascriptroom.com/exp3.php?f=include/strm/youtubeiframeplayerapi/loadVideoById.inc&ttl=%E8%A8%AD%E7%BD%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%3AloadVideoById#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to the above link and right click on the video. you will find one option which is "Get embed code", click on it and you will find the small black color pop up with text field and the text generated in this field starts with "